# Using files in sub1.domain.com from app.domain.se

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have built an app, in this app i'm gonna have multiple installations of the same app (files) but different subdomains to determine which database to use.

I would like a way to route all the subdomains to the same folder with the same files instead of having to upload the same files over and over to all the different subdomains.

The URL needs to remain the same though so i know which subdomain i am on so i can use the correct database.

Example:

- domain.com (root)
- app.domain.com (folder with all the files)
- sub1.domain.com (1 installation of the app)
- sub2.domain.com (2 installation of the app)
- sub3.domain.com (3 installation of the app)

domain.com should have it's own files.

app.domain.com should contain all the files for the app.
sub1.domain.com, sub2.domain.com, & sub3.domain.com should all use the files from app.domain.com

I've tried chaing the .htaccess in multiple ways but i can't get it to work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^../app(.*)$ /new/$1 [L,NC]
```

&

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-name.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-name.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folder/
RewriteRule (.*) /folder/$1 [L]
```

Either it just uses the index.php that is in the subdomains folder or i get a

> 400 Bad request

error.